# How to implement actionListener on BufferedImage multiple times

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, actionlistener

I am currently designing an image editor in a GUI which has several buttons which, when clicked, should apply different effects on the loaded image.  I have the effects working with an `ActionListener` but if I try to click an effect after already clicking another effect, the image turns black instead of applying the desired effect.  How do I apply multiple effects to the same image?  Here is my code for the `ButtonPanel` class, which includes the `ActionListener` and code for the effects(only three of the effects have been implemented as of yet):

```
class ButtonPanel extends JPanel
{
    //JButton makeBlue;
   BufferedImage img;
   ImagePanel ip = new ImagePanel(); 
   ButtonPanel(ImagePanel x)
   {
      final JButton makeBlue = new JButton ("Make Blue");
      final JButton makeRed = new JButton ("Make Red");
      final JButton makeGreen = new JButton ("Make Green");
      final JButton invertColors = new JButton ("Invert Colors");
      final JButton makeGreyscale = new JButton ("Greyscale");
      final JButton makeWarhol = new JButton ("Warhol");
      final JButton flipVertical = new JButton ("Flip Vertical");
      final JButton flipHorizontal = new JButton ("Flip Horizontal");
      final JButton rotateClockwise = new JButton ("Rotate Clockwise");
      setBackground(Color.RED);
      ip = x;
    //int width, height;
      //setBackground(Color.RED);
      //int height = 0;
      add(makeBlue);
      add(makeRed);
      add(makeGreen);
      add(invertColors);
      add(makeGreyscale);
      add(makeWarhol);
      add(flipVertical);
      add(flipHorizontal);
      add(rotateClockwise);
      ActionListener action = 
         new ActionListener()
         {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
               BufferedImage img = ip.getImg();

               if (e.getSource()== makeBlue)
               {


                  int width = img.getWidth();  //# of pixel columns
                  int height = img.getHeight(); //# of pixels rows


                  for(int i=0; i<width;i++)
                  {
                     for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
                     {  

                        int value = img.getRGB(i,j);
                        int y = 0xFF0000FF;
                        value = value & y;
                        img.setRGB(i,j,value);

                     }
                  }
                  ip.setImage(img);

                  setBackground(Color.GREEN);
                  repaint();

               }
               else if(e.getSource()== makeRed)
               {
                  int width = img.getWidth();  //# of pixel columns
                  int height = img.getHeight(); //# of pixels rows


                  for(int i=0; i<width;i++)
                  {
                     for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
                     {  
                     //fill in code here
                        int value = img.getRGB(i,j);
                        int y = 0xFFFF0000;
                        value = value & y;

                     //System.out.println(value);    
                        img.setRGB(i,j,value);
                     }
                  }
                  ip.setImage(img);
                  repaint();
               }
               else if(e.getSource()== makeGreen)
               {
                  int width = img.getWidth();  //# of pixel columns
                  int height = img.getHeight(); //# of pixels rows


                  for(int i=0; i<width;i++)
                  {
                     for(int j=0; j<height; j++)
                     {  
                     //fill in code here
                        int value = img.getRGB(i,j);
                        int y = 0xFF00FF00;
                        value = value & y;  
                        img.setRGB(i,j,value);
                     }
                  }
                  ip.setImage(img);
                  repaint();
               }

            }

         };

      makeBlue.addActionListener(action);
      makeRed.addActionListener(action);
      makeGreen.addActionListener(action);
      makeWarhol.addActionListener(action);
      flipVertical.addActionListener(action);
      flipHorizontal.addActionListener(action);
      rotateClockwise.addActionListener(action);
      makeGreyscale.addActionListener(action);
      invertColors.addActionListener(action);
   }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the `ImagePane`?

Comment: Do you mean `ImagePanel`?  And what do you mean by share?

Comment: Never mind, HovercraftFullOfEels has answered your question

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you're extracting all of one color out of the image, and then replacing the original image in your ImagePanel with the new extracted image that is, say if the green button is pressed, all green. Then when you try to extract red from the ImagePanel's image, you get all black because the image is now only green.

You need to save the original image somewhere if you want to extract the original colors. Perhaps you should give ImagePanel a method, `getOriginalImage()` or some such, and have it store two images, one the displayed image and one the changed one.

Better still, use an Model-View-Control pattern and store your images elsewhere off the GUI.

Comment: There must be a way to achieve this without saving a new image every time.  Could I possibly create a new image after a button is pressed and alter that new image based on the original loaded image?

Comment: @masonc15: you could do whatever you want. Try it and see.

Comment: My ImagePanel class has a getImage() method which simply returns the loaded BufferedImage but how can I allow it to store that image as well as the changed image?

Comment: @masonc15: you could give it **two** BufferedImage variables, originalImage and displayedImage, with appropriate getters and setters for both fields.

Comment: Ok, I can do that but how would that change my ActionListener method?  Would I reassign img to originalImage in each if block of the actionListener method and then change that?

Comment: @masonc15: If you have two fields in ImagePanel and appropriate getters and setters, the solution is trivial. Call the appropriate getter and setter when needed.

Comment: I have getters and setters for originalImg and changedImg but how do I implement these into the ActionListener methods for each button?

Comment: Also, why would I ever need to set the changedImg if I want to reset the image to the originalImg every time I click a button?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to accomplish this.  You can either have your class be the ActionListener (which is the way you have it set up now), or you can have a unique ActionListener for each button.  As a design decision I prefer the latter, as you can have more precise control and easier to read code this way.

Each of your buttons, menu items, and any other Object you want to have a unique effect should each have it's own ActionListener.  You can either write a new class file for each ActionListener, an inner class, or an anonymous inner class for each.  I prefer anonymous inner classes placed in line of your constructor or setup method like this:

```
JButton testButton = new JButton("Test");
testButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do stuff here
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");  
    }        
});
```

This method allows you to ignore huge conditional branches and unnecessary comparisons.  Implement the interface uniquely for each component that needs the listener.

Comment: This does not allow multiple effects to be placed onto one image, with each effect overriding the last.

Comment: Your explanation of allowing effects to overload each other is unclear to me, but if you mean for example to have flipVertical to "undo" what a previous method has done and do something else to the original, then I would maintain two `BufferedImage` fields: an originalImage and a currentImage.   This way your ActionListeners can duplicate the data from the originalImage and write the new edited image data to the currentImage, which is displayed by the GUI and updated/repainted.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the unclear language, but what you described is the desired effect.  I don't understand how I should implement both the originalImage and the currentImage in the class.  Should I repaint the originalImage at the beginning of each ActionListener for every button?

Comment: Create the original BufferedImage as a field like originalImage, perhaps in the constructor. This field should not be modified, unless perhaps you save the file. Read the BufferedImage api and there should be a way to copy the data out into a new BufferedImage local variable which you would want to edit in your actionPerformed() method. Then, assign that value to a BufferedImage currentImage field at the end of applying your effect. currentImage needs to be in the GUI layout somewhere (say, how you are handling your BufferedImage img field right now). This should only apply 1 effect at a time.